# Doing a Query in Android for Firebase inside push keys

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter that was working before i structured my firebase, now i am not sure how to get the same info with the newly structure json.

before i have this:

```
DatabaseReference userReference = mRootRef.child("Users");
query = userReference.orderByChild("name");
```

which worked with the following structure

```
"Users" : {
"dq92R8ftK2haPHJSA9undgqpmxh1" : {
  "name" : "Elvis De Abreu",
  "username" : "elvis0288"
}
```

now i added a new node called Info like this:

```
"Users" : {
"Ox0s6GhGhDcZ1vKkteeZfIyNYXI2" : {
  "Info" : {
    "email" : "elvis0288@gmail.com",
    "name" : "Elvis De Abreu",
    "username" : "111"
  }
}
```

i have tried to put `.child("Info")` and other related alternatives but that is not working. should i removed the Info and leave just the first structure or there is a way to do this? the thing is that after Info i will have another node for Games so this is why i want to have it separated

i would really appreciate some help

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not remove the `Info`, you need to use it in a correct way. You need to change this child:

```
.child(Info)
```

with

```
.child("Info")
```

See the double quote within parenthesis.

Please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String email = ds.child("Info").child("email").getValue(String.class);
            String name = ds.child("Info").child("name").getValue(String.class);
            String username = ds.child("Info").child("username").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", email + " / " + name + " / " + username);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
elvis0288@gmail.com / Elvis De Abreu / 111
```

Comment: Hello Alex, i did that but it is still not finding anything. i should have the pushid somehow there because it is not doing anything. if i do child("Info"), i will be looking for a username in Users->Info but what about the push id?

Comment: That I need a list of username from all the users but I cannot access them because I would need to know everybody push I'd for that

Comment: There is no need to know every id. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: that works if i want to populate a list but what about if i want to populate a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter that use a query 

`FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<addFriends, addFriendsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<addFriends, addFriendsViewHolder>(
                addFriends.class,
                R.layout.addfriends_row,
                addFriendsViewHolder.class,
                query`